# Hide text if previous element has elements inside of it

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem. I have a `div` inside of which there are 2 elements. First element can have children inside of it. Second element has only text.

I want to display text if only there are no elements inside of the previous element.

Ok, this is hard to understand, so here is a [reproducible fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/8sNZ9/). As you see I have 2 boxes (inside of the first element) and text in the second element. So in this way I want the div with text to be hidden. But if I will remove the boxes, the text should appear.

Using javascript there were no problems with this at all (calculate the size of the elements inside of the `span` and if 0 - show text, not 0 - hide text). The problem is that I am trying to achieve the same with pure HTML and CSS.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Salvador Dalì: to avoid faking your tests, I visited your profile due to your nickname :D

Comment: @AndreaLigios sorry, I am not really a Dali :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake it;

1. give the container a fixed height and an hidden overflow;
2. give the text a min-width of 100% and an inline-block display;

If there is something before it, the text will be pushed down, and hidden:

<kbd>[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8sNZ9/3/)</kbd>

HTML

```html
With squares, Text doesn't show:
<div class="content">
    <span>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </span>
    <div class="content-empty">Text</div>
</div>

Without, it does:
<div class="content">
    <span></span>
    <div class="content-empty">Text</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.content {
    border: 2px dashed #bbb;
    margin-top:20px;
    height: 94px;  /* new */
    overflow: hidden; /* new */
}
.box {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    display: inline-block; /* new */
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #eee;

}
.content-empty {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 94px;
    font-size: 26pt;
    display: inline-block; /* new */
    min-width: 100%; /* new */
    background: silver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible in CSS to have a selector that would select an element according to whether its sibling has children or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can use css3 for this

```
.content > span:empty + .content-empty{display: none;}
```

or

```
.content > span + .content-empty{display: none;}
```

Check [Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rx4hvn/8sNZ9/2/)

Comment: It’s `:empty:`, not `:emtpy`, it has limited browser support, and it tests for emptyness, not lack of inner elements. E.g., it does not match `<span> </span>`, still less `<span>foo</span>`.